# is it necessary to Dispose objects contains IFormFile (binary file) asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dispose, iformfile

I am working on an upload service API on asp.net core 2 and
since I am working with files
I am wondering if is it necessary to implement IDispose interface and call  Dispose() method after I am done from the object that contains the file or leave it to .net core framework to call garbage collector.

**Edit 1: (here's part of my code)**

```
 public class UploadFileModel
{
    [Required]
    public IFormFile FileBinary { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The rule of thumb is, if you use any disposable objects, put them in an `using` block and that's it. But if you keep them alive for longer, implement `IDisposable` yourself to ensure you can clean them up appropriately. For the definitive answer we need concrete code and not just an abstract description.

Comment: *leave it to .net core* - The GC will not call Dispose for you, if you have something IDisposable it's up to you to honor that contract and call Dispose either directly or via a using block.

Comment: @AlexK. I believe your comment is confused. It's generally up to the thing that creates an IDisposable object to manage the disposing of such objects. If you don't do that then you end up disposing objects that have already been disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, there is no need to do that. Usually Microsoft implements `IDisposable` on types that need to be disposed like the `DbContext` from ef-core. The implementation of `IFormFile` contains a stream, that is being disposed in a [finally statement](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/23783e4dba7c3ad8b7bf4ca60eb02f1c151e50a2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/FormFile.cs#L96) when calling

```
Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));
```

You only need to make sure that you close the stream you pass in.

For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UploadFileModel requestModel)
{
    using (var myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        requestModel.FileBinary.CopyToAsync(myMemoryStream);

        // Use new memory stream (myMemoryStream) here...

    } // myMemoryStream is disposed of here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to dispose of the object itself or the `IFormFile` because they are not IDisposable.

**But** you'll need to dispose of your own stream if you create a new copy of it (See @alsami's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51652256/894792)).

**Or** if using `OpenReadStream()` it returns a wrapper containing the underlying file stream, of type [ReferenceReadStream](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/ReferenceReadStream.cs) that *is* `IDisposable` [but it's worth knowing that it does not actually dispose of the uploaded file stream](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/ReferenceReadStream.cs#L143)... but this implementation might change in the future.

Take the following example of reading the file stream:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UploadFileModel requestModel)
{
    using (var fileStream = requestModel.FileBinary.OpenReadStream()) // returns ReferenceReadStream object
    {            
        // Make use of fileStream...

    } // using calls Dispose(), but is no-op
}
```

So there isn't any access to the original stream for you to dispose of for you to worry about, but how you use it does matter.